# XSL sub routine parameter not displaying

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, parameters, subroutine

I'm writing an XSLT to do some error checking on an XML, and I'm passing the Tag/element as a parameter to a subroutine, but I'm having trouble displaying the parameter on the error message.

I don't understand why the following doesn't display $param1 (or why its empty).

Code is as follows:

I tried with select="string($param1)" and just select="$param1"

```
<!-- ABOUT_VERSION level -->
<xsl:template match="m:ABOUT_VERSION">
    <xsl:call-template name="TagCheckCount">
        <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="m:CreatedDatetime"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="param2" select="1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="param3" select="1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Check The Numbers of Tags that exist -->   
<xsl:template name="TagCheckCount">
    <xsl:param name="param1"/> <!-- Tag -->
    <xsl:param name="param2"/> <!-- Lower Bound -->
    <xsl:param name="param3"/> <!-- Upper Bound -->

    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- If Lower and Upper Bounds are 1 -->
        <xsl:when test="$param2 = 1 and $param3 = 1">
            <!-- Check if it exists -->
            <xsl:call-template name="TagCheckExists">
                <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$param1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- Else If -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- Count is < Lower Bound -->
            <xsl:call-template name="TagCheckLT">
                <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$param1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="param2" select="$param2"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <!-- Count is > Upper Bound -->
            <xsl:call-template name="TagCheckGT">
                <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$param1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="param2" select="$param2"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


<!-- Check if Tag exists -->
<xsl:template name="TagCheckExists">
    <xsl:param name="param1"/> <!-- Tag -->

    <xsl:value-of select="string($param1)" /><br/><br/><br/>

    <!-- Check if it exists -->
    <xsl:if test="not($param1)">
        <!-- Return Error Message and XPath -->
        <p class="error">Requirement: Missing: <xsl:call-template name="GetFullPath"/><xsl:value-of select="string($param1)" /></p>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete sample of XML and XSLT to allow us to reproduce the problem. What is it you want to check, which result do you want, which one do you get?

Comment: It was the param1 from the TagCheckExists, but I realized that the supposed string wasn't properly quoted when the parameter was set in the topmost portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

When passing a STRING, you MUST include the string in single quotes inside the double quotes as such:

Otherwise:
The answer here is that because the element of param1 does not exist, then it's stringing the information in the element (which doesn't exist) so it's literally displaying nothing, correctly.